# How to stop search engines listing documents from Azure Blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a few documents stored in a Azure Blob Storage that I don't want to be listed on Google/Bing Search results. How can I do that?

Comment: Try to make blob container private or add robots.txt file in the blob container.

Comment: @sachin - Is the answer provided was helpful for you ? if so could you please accept the answer (click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in) as solution for your ask. This could be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these steps

1. Add the x-robots noindex tag to the HTTP headers of the document file.
2. Verify the x-robots noindex tag has been applied
3. Tell Googlebot to “Fetch & Render” your document in Google Search Console
4. Request that Google crawls/indexes your document
5. Wait for the document to drop out of the index.

For more details, refer to https://geoffkenyon.com/how-to-remove-pdf-files-google/